What is the most efficient way to cast int to String in Dart
Given final int i = 0;, which of the following would be the best in terms of performance and why?

'$i'
i.toString()
i as String


Such questions are usually answered by profiling - as currently written, it lacks research effort.

String interpolation is compile-time syntactic sugar.  The compiler should transform '$i' into i.toString(), so they should be equivalent.  Note that that is a transformation/conversion; it is not a "cast".  i as String is not valid; an int is not a String, and the cast will throw a runtime exception.

int as String

data type casting can only work when you are casting from a datatype that's a subtype of the datatype you are casting to.
int as num // valid
double as num // valid
int as String // not valid

because int is not a subtype of String
Using string interpolation is just calling toString() for that variable prefixed by $ dollar sign.
but there's an additional operation that has been done but it's hidden (after converting a number into string there's a concatenation process)
concatenating the converted number with the already existence String
String x = '$i';

i is converted to 'i' then concatenated with the main String ''+'i'  which yields to just 'i', if it's confusing try the following:
String x = 'hi $i';

i is converted to 'i' then concatenated with the main String 'hi' + 'i'  which yields to
'hi i'.
So, for converting a Numerical value to string to use it in assignment, using toString() method inherited from Object class is the best performant solution.

'$3' is not legal.  I think you mean something like: int i = 3; String x = '$i';.  Assuming so, are you certain that '$i' is not optimized into just i.toString() instead of '' + i.toString()?

@jamesdlin , yes $3 is not valid because 3 is not a variable, meant that a numeric variable(my bad). according to 'hi $3' is evaluated to 'hi' + '3', can that rule has an exceptional case in which that '$3' is evaluated directly to '3'.

Even for 'hi $x', there is no "extra" operation; whether you use 'hi $x' or 'hi' + x.toString(), both will involve calling x.toString() and performing a string concatenation.  The string interpolation approach might even be faster when there are multiple variables since it should avoid the Shlemiel the painter's algorithm.

'hi $x' is finally evaluated as 'hi' + x.toString()  so, what about '$x' isn't it evaluated as '' + x.toString() or it's an exceptional case as i mentoined before (i don't think so) while in the other hand String str = x.toString()  x is converted to string directly it's not costly as String str = '$x';

I would expect '$x' to be optimized to not involve any concatenation; string interpolations of the form '$x' are fairly common, and the optimization should be trivial.  I do not think that you should conclude that calling toString() directly is necessarily the most performant without evidence.
